# Trying to create a topology for SLP inspection

Tags: slp

I am trying to create a topology consists of a client,server and a gateway in the middle in order to inspect some SLP traffic.
for that i am using 2 Ubunto machines and another machine in the middle representing the firewall(which i have wireshark on).
I have downloaded openSLP and installed it on both machines, i then issued a findsrvs request for the SSH daemon using slptool and recorded all traffic.
When i put the 2 computers(client and server) without the gateway in the middle, i am able to send and receive SLP traffic and indeed finding the SSH daemon, however when i add the gateway in the middle, the packets doesn't seem to get through the gateway. I tried to understand why is this happening,till now with no success.
Can anyone think of a reason for that, maybe i need to change the routing? something with the multicast?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SLP uses broadcast packets which don't traverse through a gateway